# How to gather a tensor with unknown first (batch) dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `(?, 3, 2, 5)`.  I want to supply pairs of indices to select from the first and second dimensions of that tensor, that have shape `(3, 2)`.

If I supply 4 such pairs, I would expect the resulting shape to be `(?, 4, 5)`.  I'd thought this is what what `batch_gather` is for: to "broadcast" gathering indices over the first (batch) dimension.  But this is not what it's doing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 3, 2, 5))


indices = tf.constant([
    [2, 1],
    [2, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 1]
], tf.int32)

tf.batch_gather(data, indices)
```

Which results in `<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_3:0' shape=(4, 2, 2, 5) dtype=float32>` instead of the shape that I was expecting.

How can I do what I want without explicitly indexing the batches (which have an unknown size)?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid `transpose` and Python loops, and I think this works.  This was the setup:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

shape = None, 3, 2, 5
data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape)
idxs_list = [
    [2, 1],
    [2, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 1]
]
idxs = tf.constant(idxs_list, tf.int32)
```

This allows us to gather the results:

```
batch_size, num_idxs, num_channels = tf.shape(data)[0], tf.shape(idxs)[0], shape[-1]

batch_idxs = tf.math.floordiv(tf.range(0, batch_size * num_idxs), num_idxs)[:, None]
nd_idxs = tf.concat([batch_idxs, tf.tile(idxs, (batch_size, 1))], axis=1)

gathered = tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(data, nd_idxs), (batch_size, num_idxs, num_channels))
```

When we run with a batch size of `4`, we get a result with shape `(4, 4, 5)`, which is `(batch_size, num_idxs, num_channels)`.

```
vals_shape = 4, *shape[1:]
vals = np.arange(int(np.prod(vals_shape))).reshape(vals_shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = gathered.eval(feed_dict={data: vals})
```

Which ties out with `numpy` indexing:

```
x, y = zip(*idxs_list)
assert np.array_equal(result, vals[:, x, y])
```

Essentially, `gather_nd` wants batch indices in the first dimension, and those have to be repeated once for each index pair (i.e., `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, ...]` if there are 4 index pairs).

Since there doesn't seem to be a `tf.repeat`, I used `range` and `floordiv`, and then `concat`ed the batch indices with the desired (x, y) indices (which are themselves tiled `batch_size` times).

Answer (score 0):

Using `tf.batch_gather` the leading dimensions of the shape of the `tensor` should match with the leading dimension of the shape of the `indice` tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2, 3, 2, 5))
print(data.shape) // (2, 3, 2, 5)

# shape of indices, [2, 3]
indices = tf.constant([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]
])  
print(tf.batch_gather(data, indices).shape) # (2, 3, 2, 5)
# if shape of indice was (2, 3, 1) the output would be 2, 3, 1, 5
```

What you rather want is to use `tf.gather_nd` as the following

```
data_transpose = tf.transpose(data, perm=[2, 1, 0, 3])
t_transpose = tf.gather_nd(data_transpose, indices)
t = tf.transpose(t_transpose, perm=[1, 0, 2])
print(t.shape) # (?, 4, 5)
```

Comment: The docs for `gather_nd` say `If value.shape[axis] is not known, ValueError is raised.` and indeed, I get a `ValueError` when I `tf.unstack(data)` if the batch dimension is `?`.

Comment: @capitalistcuttle, I edited my answer using transpose over the initial data in order to avoid the unstack error